# NHibernate ITransaction and pure domain model

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, persistence-ignorance

I'm trying to write my **Domain Model as persistence-ignorant as possible**. The only thing I'm doing right now is marking every property and method `virtual`, as NHibernate requires that for lazy-loading.

In my **domain model assembly** I define some repository interfaces:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase {
    TEntity Get(int id);
    /* ... */
}
public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product> { ... }
```

Then I have a **data assembly**. This one will reference NHibernate, it knows about its existence. This is the assembly that implements those repository interfaces:

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> {
    public TEntity Get(ind id) { ... }
    /* ... */
}
public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product>, IProductRepository {
    /* ... */
}
```

and so on.

Now I wanted to **implement a transaction functionality** to my repositories. To do so, I would add a `BeginTransaction` method on my IRepository interface. However, I cannot define its return type as `NHibernate.ITransaction`, since I want to keep the domain model persistence-ignorant, and not be forced to reference NHibernate's assembly from my domain model assembly.

What would you do?

Would you simply implement a `void BeginTransaction()`, a `void Commit()`, and a `void RollBack()` methods on the interface, and let **the repository implementation manage the `ITransaction` object internally**?

Or would you find a way to **expose the `ITransaction` object** to let the client manage the transaction directly with it, instead of using repository's methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) which has already implemented everything you talk about, including generic repositories with transactions support. The solution there is that IRepository has DbContext property which encapsulates transactions (it's actually an interface).
This is the first of the options that you described (custom transactions interface which hides NHibernate). And it works well.

I guess you can even re-use S#arp code regardless if you intend to use the full framework.

Answer (score 0):

IMO Transactions should always start and end in business logic, in other words the transaction should start in the service layer not the repository layer and the repository should enlist it's self in the transaction, ideally this would be done implicitly.

Now if you're using NH then if your service and repositories share the same 'session' (which they should) then you can call 'BeginTransaction' in the service layer and commit or roll back as required:

Eg, imagine this a method on a service:

> ```
>   public void RegisterCustomer(Customer customer)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             using(var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
>             {
>                 _customerRepository.Save(customer);
>                 _customerSurveyRepository.Save(customerSurvey);
>                 // DO What ever else you want...
>                 transaction.Commit();
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception exn)
>         {
>             throw new AMException(FAILED_REGISTRATION, exn);
>         }
>      }
> ```

How the repositories obtain a reference to the same Session can be solved by injecting in the constructors or by using a the SessionFactory to obtain the current session...